# Using serialized PHP arrays in wpDataTables in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to use a serialized PHP array to create a table from a database using wpDataTables. I chose to use a serialized PHP array instead of an SQL query because I want to use URL parameters to choose specific data from the database to include in the table.

What I did so far is create the PHP script shown below.

However, I am not getting the expected output and I am unable to use this script to create the table on wpDataTables.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("#######", "#######", "######", "######");

if(!$mysqli)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$par = $_GET['zipcode'];

if(!$par) {
  $zcode = 75001;
}
else {
  $zcode = $par;
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT RepCompany,Product,kwh500,kwh1000 FROM plans
join zip_codes
  ON plans.area_id = zip_codes.area_id
 WHERE zip_codes.zip_code=$zcode");

echo serialize($result);

?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on “not getting the expected output”

Answer (score 0):

The `query` method returns a [result set object.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) To get the results themselves, you need to use the fetch methods on the result set, for example [fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
echo serialize($result->fetch_all());
```